# Hazelcast deployment on Kubernetes without Cluster Roles

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I have spring boot application with embedded hazelcast that I am trying to deploy on a shared Kubernetes platform. I want to use kubernetes API strategy for auto discovery. Can I do this without creating Cluster Roles and Cluster Role Bindings and have just Role and Role Binding created under my namespace. If yes, what would the rbac.yaml look like ?

Tried creating the following roles and role bindings but no auto discovery so far.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-role
  namespace: dev
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints 
      - pods
      - nodes
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-role-binding
  namespace: dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: hazelcast-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: dev
```